# merging/overlaying 2 scatter plots using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library (ggplot2)
data (mtcars)
mtcars$gear   <- factor (mtcars$gear)
mtcars$cyl    <- factor (mtcars$cyl)
transmission <- data.frame ( code = c(1, 0),
                             type = c("manual", "automatic"))
mtcars$transmission <- setNames (transmission$type, transmission$code) [as.character (mtcars$am)]
my.formula <- y ~ x
  
p <- ggplot       (data = mtcars, aes(x=hp, y=mpg, group = 1)) +
     facet_wrap   (~transmission, strip.position = "top", scales = "free", nrow = 1) +
     ggtitle      ("car horsepower (hp) to effiency (mpg) based on cylinder and number of gears for American vs others cars") +
     geom_point   ( size = 6, aes ( shape=cyl, color=cyl) ) +
     scale_color_manual (name       = "number of cylinder",
                         labels     = c (paste (levels(mtcars$cyl), "cylinders")),
                         values     = c("turquoise", "orange", "red")) +
      
     scale_shape_manual  (name       = "number of cylinder",
                          labels     = c (paste (levels(mtcars$cyl), "cylinders")),
                          values     = c (15, 16, 17)) +
    geom_smooth  (data = mtcars, method="lm",
                  formula = my.formula,
                  se = FALSE,
                  color = "blue",
                  fill = "blue") +

    stat_poly_eq (formula = my.formula,
                  aes(label = paste(after_stat(eq.label), ..rr.label.., sep = "~~~")),
                  parse = TRUE,
                  size = 4,
                  col = "black") +

    theme        (panel.spacing    = unit(0, "lines"),
                  strip.background = element_blank(),
                  plot.title       = element_text(hjust = 0.5,
                                                  color = "black",
                                                  size  = 14,
                                                  face  = "bold.italic"),
                  strip.placement = "outside")
print(p)
```

[image: output without gear information]

Then I wish to add a layered scatterplot on top of this indicating the number of gears goes with each data point.

```
    geom_point   ( size = 2, aes ( shape=gear, color="black" ) ) +
    scale_shape_manual  (name       = "number of gears",
                         labels     = c (paste (levels(mtcars$gears), "gears")),
                         values     = c (1, 3, 4)) +
```

Simply adding this second geom_point causes the plot to fail in this case as other posts have suggested and appears to work in less complicated figures.

Ideally the legend would keep the shape and color for the gears and add a second legend with the shape and color of the gears that will be overlayed. I've tried few things including this below but just cant get ggplot to reposed to the overlaying plot.

```
library (ggplot2)
data (mtcars)
mtcars$gear   <- factor (mtcars$gear)
mtcars$cyl    <- factor (mtcars$cyl)
transmission <- data.frame ( code = c(1, 0),
                             type = c("manual", "automatic"))

mtcars$transmission <- setNames (transmission$type, transmission$code) [as.character (mtcars$am)]
my.formula <- y ~ x
  
p <- ggplot       (data = mtcars, aes(x=hp, y=mpg, group = 1)) +
     facet_wrap   (~transmission, strip.position = "top", scales = "free", nrow = 1) +
     ggtitle      ("car horsepower (hp) to effiency (mpg) based on cylinder and number of gears for American vs others cars") +
     geom_point   ( size = 6 ) +
     scale_color_manual (name        = "number of cylinder and gears",
                         labels      = c (paste (levels(mtcars$cyl), "cylinders"), paste (levels(mtcars$gear), "gears")),
                         values      = c ("turquoise", "orange", "red", rep("black", 3))) +
      
     scale_shape_manual  (name       = "number of cylinder and gears",
                          labels     = c (paste (levels(mtcars$cyl), "cylinders"), paste (levels(mtcars$gear), "gears")),
                          values     = c (15, 16, 17, 1, 3, 4)) +

     scale_size_manual  (name       = "number of cylinder and gears",
                         labels     = c (paste (levels(mtcars$cyl), "cylinders"), paste (levels(mtcars$gear), "gears")),
                         values     = c (rep (6, 3), rep (2, 3))) +

    geom_smooth  (data = mtcars, method="lm",
                  formula = my.formula,
                  se = FALSE,
                  color = "blue",
                  fill =  "blue") +

    stat_poly_eq (formula = my.formula,
                  aes(label = paste(after_stat(eq.label), ..rr.label.., sep = "~~~")),
                  parse = TRUE,
                  size = 4,
                  col = "black") +

    theme        (panel.spacing    = unit(0, "lines"),
                  strip.background = element_blank(),
                  plot.title       = element_text(hjust = 0.5,
                                                  color = "black",
                                                  size  = 14,
                                                  face  = "bold.italic"),
                  strip.placement = "outside")
print(p)
```

[image: second attempt that has failed]

This clearly doesn't work and reverts the graph back to standard.  My data that I am working with is obviously different, but this does demonstrate what is needed. Does anyone have any good suggestions on how I could better approach this? I'd prefer not to use other libraries, if we can help it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In vanilla `ggplot2` you can have only scale per aesthetic, i.e. adding a second `scale_shape_...` will overwrite the first and as you now have 6 categories (3 gears and 3 cyls) you will get an error as either of you manuals scales provides only three values. One option to fix your issue and get a second legend would be to use the `ggnewscale` package which by adding a `ggnewscale::new_scale("shape")` straight before your second `geom_point` allows to add a second shape scale and legend. Additionally I moved `color="black"` outside of `aes()` for the second `geom_point` for similar reasons:

Note: I also switched to passing some lambda functions to the `labels=` arguments to add the suffixes to the legend entries.

And as a suggestion, from a data viz point of view using both color and shape to code the same piece of information (aka the number of cylinders) should be avoided, especially as you are using shapes for a different piece of information (aka the number of gears). Doing so will also allow to drop one of the shape scales and did not require `ggnewscale`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpmisc)

mtcars$gear <- factor(mtcars$gear)
mtcars$cyl <- factor(mtcars$cyl)
transmission <- data.frame(
  code = c(1, 0),
  type = c("manual", "automatic")
)
mtcars$transmission <- setNames(transmission$type, transmission$code)[as.character(mtcars$am)]

my.formula <- y ~ x

library(ggplot2)
library(ggpmisc)

ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = mpg, group = 1)) +
  facet_wrap(~transmission, strip.position = "top", scales = "free", nrow = 1) +
  ggtitle(
    "car horsepower (hp) to effiency (mpg) based on cylinder and number of gears for American vs others cars"
  ) +
  geom_point(size = 6, aes(shape = cyl, color = cyl)) +
  scale_color_manual(
    name = "number of cylinder",
    labels = ~ paste(.x, "cylinders"),
    values = c("turquoise", "orange", "red")
  ) +
  scale_shape_manual(
    name = "number of cylinder",
    labels = ~ paste(.x, "cylinders"),
    values = c(15, 16, 17)
  ) +
  geom_smooth(
    data = mtcars, method = "lm",
    formula = my.formula,
    se = FALSE,
    color = "blue",
    fill = "blue"
  ) +
  stat_poly_eq(
    formula = my.formula,
    aes(label = paste(after_stat(eq.label), ..rr.label.., sep = "~~~")),
    parse = TRUE,
    size = 4,
    col = "black"
  ) +
  theme(
    panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines"),
    strip.background = element_blank(),
    plot.title = element_text(
      hjust = 0.5,
      color = "black",
      size = 14,
      face = "bold.italic"
    ),
    strip.placement = "outside"
  ) +
  ggnewscale::new_scale("shape") +
  geom_point(size = 2, aes(shape = gear), color = "black") +
  scale_shape_manual(
    name = "number of gears",
    labels = ~ paste(.x, "gears"),
    values = c(1, 3, 4)
  )
```

[image]

Comment: @AllanCameron Yeah. You are right. Will fix the legend . And of course should using both color and shape for the same piece of information be avoided. Will add this as a suggestion.

Comment: there is an s on the end of mtcars$gear.  remove the s and it works well.

Comment: @AllanCameron the OG data set works best with this format, the "gears" symbols better identifies samples that unique or outliers, this mark does not affect how the results are interpreted.  I might make the points all the same shape because it obviously does the same thing as color, however I am just exploring the data and pushing ggplot beyond what I know.  Thank for the help.

Comment: @stefan thanks for the help, this solution works really well for what I am doing.